# Does --patch-module show up reflectively?

Tags: java, java-module, java-platform-module-system

Suppose `java` is invoked with `--patch-module`.  From within the running program, is there any way to discover that the patched module contains classes and packages in more than one location? I failed to find anything appropriate in `ModuleLayer`, `ModuleReference` and the like. (The `jdk.module.path` System property obviously does not contain any helpful information either, and there is no other promising-looking System property other than `sun.java.command`, which sure looks like I should not rely on it.)

Comment: FWIW, module patching is not part of the Java specification. It is a JDK specific mechanism. So, it is not exposed directly in the module reflection API.

Comment: Thanks; for my money this comment should be the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Module patching is not part of the Java specification. It is a JDK specific mechanism. So, it is not exposed directly in the module reflection API.

There is a way to detect patched modules though. This is a bit convoluted, but it seems to work:

```
public static boolean isPatched(Module mod) throws IOException {
    ModuleReader reader = mod.getLayer()
      .configuration().findModule(mod.getName()).orElseThrow()
      .reference()
      .open();

    String modInfoName = "module-info.class";
    URI modInfo = reader.find(modInfoName).orElseThrow();
    String modInfoStr = modInfo.toString();
    String root = modInfoStr.substring(0, modInfoStr.length() - modInfoName.length());


    List<String> resources;
    try (Stream<String> stream = reader.list()) {
        resources = stream.toList();
    }
    for (String res : resources) {
        URI uri = reader.find(res).orElseThrow();
        if (!uri.toString().contains(root)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

This relies on the fact that `module-info.class` can not be patched over, so it should always be found in the module's 'root' location.

After finding the URI of the module-info.class resource, we can look at all the other resources to see if they are read from the same root path. If not, this means the module is patched.

(The example does a bit of hand-waving WRT error handling, but hopefully you get the idea).

Comment: It might be easier to obtain the `location()` from the `ModuleReference`.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn I looked at that, but the format seems to be different from the URIs of the resources returned by list() + find()

Comment: Interesting. This is by the way the thing that matters for the code source property for the protection domain.

Comment: Mind that the `ModuleReader` should be closed at the end of the operation. Further, I’d rather use the FileSystem API, i.e. `Path root = Path.of(reader.find("module-info.class") .orElseThrow()).getParent();` and in the loop: `if(!Path.of(reader.find(res).orElseThrow()).startsWith(root)) return true;` There’s one minor catch: it only works if the patch source location actually contributes at least one resource, in other words, it doesn’t work if the directory is empty.